# NSDateComponents week is working differently on iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, nsdatecomponents

`NSDateComponents` `week` is deprecated since iOS8. Apple suggest using `weekOfMonth` or `weekOfYear` instead, depending on the context, but they are working in a different way. For example:

```
components1 = [calendar components:NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit
                          fromDate:[self date7DaysAgo]
                            toDate:[NSDate date]
                           options:0];
```

components1 returns month = 0, week = 1, day = 0, `weekOfMonth` and `weekOfYear` are both equal to 2147483647 (integer maximum value).

```
components2 = [calendar components:NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit
                          fromDate:[self date30DaysAgo]
                            toDate:[NSDate date]
                           options:0];
```

components2 returns month = 1 (I know it depends, but its just an example), week = 0, day = 0, `weekOfMonth` and `weekOfYear` are both equal to 2147483647 (integer maximum value).

`Week` returns number of weeks during some period (if it was a week or it multiple) and it is completely different than number of a week in month or year. Why would Apple suggest using this instead?

Comment: What is performed by method date7DaysAgo and date30DaysAgo?

Comment: Date 7 or 30 days ago is returned. It can be for example: 
'[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60 * 60 * 24 * 7] (I know that due to daylight saving time or something else it can differ, but again, it is just an example).

Comment: If you actually choose to look at the documentation, NSWeekCalendarUnit is "Deprecated in iOS 8.0."  (However, oddly, so are all the other units.)

Comment: I would have expected a "Deprecated in iOS8" warning Though :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `NSWeekOfMonthCalendarUnit` or `NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit` instead of `NSWeekCalendarUnit`.

Comment: My bad. I thought it was working differently on iOS8 but weekOfYear will do the job here.

Comment: Those are deprecated in 8.  (And good luck finding the replacements in Apple's documentation.)